# PHP - composite input field validation laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Need help to validate(unique validation) the composition of two inputs (i.e event date and time)to make sure whether they have been already used.

Already made the relevant two columns as a composite key on database using migration.

At the moment it delivers a SQL query exception upon submission of a duplicate entry.
(SQLSTATE[2300]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry)

**Here is my table migration**

```
Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('email');
$table->string('fname');
$table->string('lname');
$table->date('event_date');
$table->string('t_session');
$table->unique(array('event_date', 't_session'));
$table->timestamps();
});
```

**here what happens when I submit My Form**

```
$event = new Event;
    $event->email = $request->input('email');
    $event->event_date = $request->input('event_date');
    $event->t_session = $request->input('t_session');
    $event->fname = $request->input('fname');
    $event->lname = $request->input('lname');
    $event->save();

    return redirect('/events')->with('success', 'Event Created Successfully');
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and the SQL query

Comment: @Kingsley I'v e updated my code snippets. Thanks in advance for the kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on a laracast discussion :
[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-validate-unique-combination][1]